# Windows Message box for each selection

Tags: powershell

I have a script which checks a certain subset of groups a user has then prompts them if they have removed the access or the group. I want to improve this or change it up so it brings up a windows message box instead. I have managed to get it to work however when it circles the for each entry it displays the whole list in the box. It will do this for each of the groups. So if it finds 5 groups it displays 5 times. I am looking for it to show each one individually in order. So you click past group1 it then shows group2 and so on.

I have the below code which is nearly there but unsure how to get the display i want.

```
    $AuditGroups = (Get-ADUser -identity $Username -properties * | Select-object MemberOf).MemberOf | Sort-Object
    $AGSelection = @($AuditGroups | Select-String -pattern "Audit" |ForEach-Object{ (Get-ADGroup -Identity "$_" -Properties SAMAccountName).SAMAccountName})
    
    If ($true -eq $AGSelection){
    
    ForEach ($user in $AGSelection) {
    
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
    $ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
    $MessageboxTitle = “Audit Group found”
    $Messageboxbody = “Please remove the users access from $AGSelection”
    $MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($Messageboxbody,$MessageboxTitle,$ButtonType,$messageicon)
    
    $Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)
    
    Write-Host "Your Choice is $result"
    
    }
    else{

Write-Host "User not in any groups"

    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you wanna change `“Please remove the users access from $AGSelection”` to `“Please remove the users access from $user”`